# Array of function pointer pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

If I want an array of pointers to something, I declare it like this:

```
Type** var = new Type*[8];
```

and use it like this:

```
if(var[0] != NULL)
    // Do something
```

But how can I have an array of function pointers in a similar fashion? Something like this maybe:

```
typedef bool (*Handler)(int, int);
Handler** list = new Handler*[8];

...

Handler* func = list[0];
if(func != NULL)
    *func(6, 5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have:

```
typedef    bool (*Handler)(int, int);

Handler* list = new Handler[8];

Handler func = list[0];
if (func != NULL)
    func(6, 5);
```

Just don't put an extra `*`

Comment: I love you. Now I feel silly... (will accept answer when SO allows me)

Comment: Function pointers syntax can be sometimes confusing, methods pointers is another funny thing :D

Comment: Nitpick but you can put in the `*` you just have to bracket it correctly, `(*func)(6, 5);`. This was the original C syntax (which is why I still find myself using it) but at some point the `*` became optional.